# Divisors of the form $4n+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I read a question
[Number of divisors of the form $(4n+1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374552/number-of-divisors-of-the-form-4n1)
.

In the soultion

> Any positive divisor of $2^2\cdot 3^3\cdot 5^3\cdot 7^5$ of the form
>   $4k+1$ is a number of the form: $$3^a\cdot 5^b\cdot 7^c$$ with $0\leq
> > a\leq 3,0\leq b\leq 3,0\leq c\leq 5$ and $\color{red}{a+c}$ being even. There are:
>   $$\frac{4\cdot 4\cdot 6}{2}=\color{red}{48}$$

**why a+c should be even?**

Plz use easy language. I don't know the meaning of mod....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

As $3=4-1,7=8-1$

$$3^a7^c=(4-1)^a(8-1)^b$$

using Binomial Expansion, we can prove it to be of the form $4c+(-1)^{a+b}$ where $c$ is some integer