# Number of divisors of $2^2\cdot 3^3\cdot 5^3\cdot 7^5$ of the form $4n+1,n\in N$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, permutations, combinations

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1374552/794439), the OP asks to find the number of divisors of $2^2\cdot 3^3\cdot 5^3\cdot 7^5$ which are of the form $4n+1,n\in N$. The [top answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1374559/794439) points out that the required divisor is of the form $$3^a\cdot 5^b\cdot 7^c$$ with $0\leq a\leq 3,0\leq b\leq 3,0\leq c\leq 5$ and $a+c$ being even. The answer therefore is, apparently, $(4 \cdot 4 \cdot 6)/2=48$.

But this is wrong according to my book: the correct answer is $47$. Obviously, one case has been overcounted, but which? As far as I know, the person who wrote the top answer employed a fairly standard approach and should have arrived at the correct answer.

Comment: I guess the book uses $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$, so it doesn't count $1 = 4\cdot 0 + 1$.

Comment: Well, at a guess, the official solution excludes $(a,b,c)=(0,0,0)$, i.e. it excludes the divisor $1$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Ah, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of divisors of the form $(4n+1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374552/number-of-divisors-of-the-form-4n1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by Daniel Fischer and lulu, my book considers $0 \notin N$, so discounts the case where $a=b=c=0$, i.e., $4(0)+1=1$.